# MySql arithmetic differs from Excel

Tags: mysql

I have plugged the same calculation into Excel and MySql and they are quite different.

Excel:

```
=(12^1.2299)/(12^1.16793+12^1.20053)*2.29761*11
```

MySql

```
select ((12^1.2299)/(12^1.16793+12^1.20053))*2.29761*11.0 AS Wrong
```

I believe Excel gives the correct answer of 14.14 while MySql gets 12.63.

I have put additional brackets and decimals in but it makes no difference,

Why is MySql so wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the MySQL POWER() function instead of using the caret symbol. For example, instead of using `12^1.2299` you will want to use `POWER(12,1.2299)`.

Answer (score 1):

[The `^` operator is a bitwise XOR in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html). You should use the `POWER()` function to calculate exponents instead of `^`.

Example:

```
SELECT POWER(12,1.2299)/(POWER(12,1.16793)+POWER(12,1.20053))*2.29761*11.0 AS Correct
```

Returns `14.143896230490112`